# Rails edit scaffold generators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, edit, scaffold

I am trying to edit rails scaffold generators where I want to add custom action to my controllers and add them into routes. I can edit model generators by adding this code in my lib directory:

```
 #/lib/template/active_record/model.rb
      <% module_namespacing do -%>
class <%= class_name %> < <%= parent_class_name.classify %>

  def self.import1(file)

    spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file.path)
          header = spreadsheet.row(1)
          (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
            row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
            puts row.to_hash
            product = find_by(id: row["id"]) || new
            product.attributes = row.to_hash
            product.save!
          end

  end

<% attributes.select(&:reference?).each do |attribute| -%>
  belongs_to :<%= attribute.name %><%= ', polymorphic: true' if attribute.polymorphic? %><%= ', required: true' if attribute.required? %>
<% end -%>
<% attributes.select(&:token?).each do |attribute| -%>
  has_secure_token<% if attribute.name != "token" %> :<%= attribute.name %><% end %>
<% end -%>
<% if attributes.any?(&:password_digest?) -%>
  has_secure_password
<% end -%>
end
<% end -%>
```

When I am generating rails g scaffold my_controller name:string .. I can see it is invoking resource_route. And it adds a line to my routes.

I want a solution where I can add two actions like test and import in my controller whenever I generate scaffold and add them into routes. I can edit my templates by adding this:

```
 #/lib/templates/scaffold/index.html.erb
```

What do I need to write or copy in my lib folder which can generate a controller with two actions like:

```
  def import
   # Module1.import(params[:file])
   ProductionProductivity7.import1(params[:file])
   redirect_to tests_path, notice: "Products imported."
  end
```

And in my routes I want this to be added like:

```
 resources :production_productivity9s do
     collection { post :import }
     collection { get :dropdown }
     collection { get :test }
  end
```

Instead of resources :production_productivity9s. I want a solution to edit controller and routes. I am searching on net and I don't see any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to edit the resource route and add some action to my controller I added this code for editing my routes:

```
#rails/generators/rails/resource_route

module Rails
  module Generators
  class ResourceRouteGenerator < NamedBase # :nodoc:
    # Properly nests namespaces passed into a generator
    #
    #   $ rails generate resource admin/users/products
    #
    # should give you
    #
    #   namespace :admin do
    #     namespace :users do
    #       resources :products
    #     end
    #   end
    def add_resource_route
      return if options[:actions].present?

      depth = 0
      lines = []

      # Create 'namespace' ladder
      # namespace :foo do
      #   namespace :bar do
      regular_class_path.each do |ns|
        lines << indent("namespace :#{ns} do\n", depth * 2)
        depth += 1
      end

      # inserts the primary resource
      # Create route
      #     resources 'products'
      #  lines << indent(%{resources :#{file_name.pluralize}\n }, depth * 2) 
      lines << indent(%{resources :#{file_name.pluralize} do 
                collection { post :import }
                collection { get :dropdown }
                collection { get :test }
                end \n}, depth * 2)

      # Create `end` ladder
      #   end
      # end
      until depth.zero?
        depth -= 1
        lines << indent("end\n", depth * 2)
      end

      route lines.join
    end
  end
end
```

end

source code for resource route : [Resource Route](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/resource_route/resource_route_generator.rb)

I was able to edit my controller I used this code to edit:

```
 #/lib/templates/rails/scaffold_controller/controller.rb
   def import
  <%= class_name %>.import1(params[:file])
  redirect_to tests_path, notice: "Products imported."
 end
```

Source code for scaffold controller edit is: [Scaffold_Controller](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/scaffold_controller/templates/controller.rb.tt)